# Is it possible to get the transaction count for a contract in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, accounts, addresses, nonce

Is there built-in functionality for getting the transaction count (nonce) for an account in Solidity?

Comment: No, there isn't. You need to have a counter in your fallback function or function that processes incoming transactions if I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, an account's transaction count (nonce) is not available inside a smart contract.

The only property that a smart contract can obtain about any address, is its balance in wei:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related